# Cargar datos en $scope dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo una llamada a una API, en la cuál recupero varios datos.

Sólo quiero mostrar algunos de los campos, por lo tanto he creado un array con los campos que quiero mostrar:

```
var CamposAPI = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
var campo = CamposAPI[i]; (está dentro de un for, según los campos que contenga CamposAPI)
```

El cuál utilizo para luego mostrarlo con la siguiente línea:

```
$scope.campo = response.data["Clientes"][0][campo];
```

Si hago un console.log se ven correctamente los datos, pero al bindarlos no llegan a la vista.

Seguro que estoy haciendo algo mal en la parte de $scope.campo pero no veo el que.

Añado el codigo de la vista:

```
<md-card layout-gt-sm="row" layout-padding  ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left"><strong>a</strong></td>
        <td class="text-left" colspan="5">{{a}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left"><strong>v</strong></td>
        <td class="text-left">{{b}}</td>
        <td class="text-left"><strong>c</strong></td>
        <td class="text-left" colspan="3">{{c}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</mdcard>
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes subir el codigo en la vista?

Comment: Añadido el código de la vista

Comment: Bueno @Diego lo que veo es que el error esta en la vista, en donde estas iterando sobre campo?, o en donde llamas campo desde tu vista?

Comment: La idea que llevaba (y como funciona perfectamente metiendo los campos a piñón) es el hacer un $scope.a, $scope.b y así con todos los datos introducidos en el array campo. No se si es una buena idea. Espero a ver que me decís, si no, replanteo la estructura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso pienso que debes hacer algo asi.

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-left"><strong>a</strong></td>
    <td class="text-left" colspan="5">{{campo[0]}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-left"><strong>v</strong></td>
    <td class="text-left">{{campo[1]}}</td>
    <td class="text-left"><strong>c</strong></td>
    <td class="text-left" colspan="3">{{campo[2]}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Ya tienes la matriz entonces el esfuerzo de asignar un dato en $scope para cada uno no es necesario. Pon la matriz en $scope y acceder a ellos por la matriz.

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que estaba buscando. Ahora mismo lo implementare.